# APPHOST9623: The app couldn't resolve ms-appx:

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

Developed a hybrid mobile app on cordova 3.0. Trying to deploy in android, windowsPhone 8.1 and ios. Have been facing problems with IOS 8.2 in macincloud. When upgraded to CTP 3.1 in Visual Studio, it upgraded to Cordova 3.7, now the app is completely broke in windows and android throwing errors like

> APPHOST9623: The app couldn't resolve ms-appx:.....

All the references are broke.

Also xmlhttprequest is also broke in ripple.

Looking for some real good help here. Please ping me soon.

Comment: The issue is resolved by commenting the PlatformOverrides.js reference. I think this is not required anymore in new versions of Cordova. This information I could not find anywhere. Hope this saves somebody elses time.